# Forwarding All Traffic to http proxy (Tunneling)

Tags: c#, c++, networking

i need an open source app (c# or c++ ) that grab all windows http traffic and forward to an http proxy
there is an app name Proxifier do this but i want open source project to embed to my app or at least a free commandline program that do this
thanks so much

Comment: if you only need http traffic redirected, you could probably get it done with [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) -- if you can forgo the open-source requirement. For some reason I thought fiddler was opensource though

Comment: thank U. I will test it and let you know

Comment: I couldn't find where is the configuration of forwarding packet

Comment: Tools > Options > Gateway > Manual Proxy Configuration.

Comment: @hometoast thank you so much I used fiddlerCore instead and my problem solved. Please post ur answer and I'll Accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/) to first intercept web traffic and force it to your own proxy. 
`Tools > Options > Gateway` and set your proxy.

Or consume [FiddlerCore](http://fiddler2.com/fiddlercore) in your own app.

Answer (score 1):

Commandline wise I can recommend proxychains.

http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/

For a full blown proxying solution you might want to look into Privoxy.

http://www.privoxy.org/

There is also squid proxy for instance and many other solutions. The solutions I mentioned are rather unix/linux centric so you might need cygwin or similar to drive this.

Comment: I dont want proxy server. I need an app like proxifier atomatically forward all traphic to external proxy server. your solotions are proxy server that listen on specific ip port but i need an app forward all packet atomatically.Most programs haven't proxy configuration ability so i need to tunnel whole http packet

Answer (score 1):

The last time I needed something like this I used the [mentalis](http://mentalis.org/) proxy, which has a BSD style license.