# Is there any command line software to proxy a single application with a single proxy?

Tags: c#, proxy, command-line-interface

Sorry if I did not post in the correct StackExchange branch.

I'm searching for a software runnable via command line interface (to be precise, on Windows) to tunnel a single .exe file through a single proxy.
A cli version of Proxifier, for example.

Searching through the net I found this one 
http://proxifier.sourceforge.net/ but it's surely outdated and I can't edit and compile the solution to edit the path of the config file.

Can anyone help me?

The possible duplicate indicated by @M.Hassan is different because the OP of that question asked for something that would redirect *all* the traffic from Windows, I need it for each single application I'll need.

For example:

```
proxy-software ./path/to/software_i_need_to_be_proxed_a.exe foo:bar@89.89.89.89
proxy-software ./path/to/software_i_need_to_be_proxed_b.exe foo:bar@89.89.89.109
proxy-software ./path/to/software_i_need_to_be_proxed_c.exe foo:bar@123.22.66.99
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forwarding All Traffic to http proxy (Tunneling)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570548/forwarding-all-traffic-to-http-proxy-tunneling)

Comment: @M.Hassan I thought the edit would have cited you. Sorry, I made you wait.

Comment: have a look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_proxifiers, it may help.

Comment: at http://proxifier.com/ product, you can define rules for Proxification application to be based on application names, IP addresses, hostnames and port numbers and save to a profile.

Comment: @M.Hassan Proxifier.com product is great, I used it a bunch of times. But it needs a GUI, I can't do what I wrote in the edit, proxing every single app by a single cli command.

So basically, what I need is a software like the paid proxifier one, but runnable without a lot of configurations and in a command line interface, preferably on Windows.

Comment: You can block all and create profile per application only

Comment: From feature of proxifier it works as a service, which may be managed by command. review: http://proxifier.com/documentation/v3/manual.htm

Comment: @M.Hassan How would one identify these commands? I am attempting to do the same as OP, doesn't seem to be any solution posted! I need to proxy multiple instances of the same application, using different proxies!